# Glue Jobs creating table and writing in s3 throwing __PLACEHOLDER__ error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I am trying to create a table while writing data into s3 from glue. Below error came. Any resolution or any optimized way to create table and write.

```
orderdf.write.format('parquet').partitionBy('region_id','mar','date','ised').saveAsTable('bdling.custre',path=target_s3_path)
```

Error

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: file:./s3/bda-us-east-1/bdling/custre-PLACEHOLDER
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got this one resolved. First define the database path in Glue Metadata. My s3 path had issues which I resolved. This was the solution.